# How to make faye client on server side in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye

I have been working on [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/) gem for couple of days. I have created Faye client at client-side using below code:

```
 var client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:9292/faye');
   $.get("/chatroom", function (data)
    {
     var UserId = data.user
     client.subscribe("/message/"+UserId+"", function(data)
      {
        //rest of the code
      });
    })
```

but I want this activity to be done on server side how to achieve this?  Whenever a user gets login he should be subscribed to push server.

Comment: Why do it on the server side? Why not when the client receives the response from the login server service?

Comment: I'm trigging this code on page load. which will be triggered unnecessarily  every now and then, when the page gets loaded.

Comment: But how is your login logic in the front-end?

Comment: login logic is not at the front end. its on server side itself. but somewhere I have to call this function .so I called it on the page which gets loaded after successful authentication.

Comment: So this page is loaded after login is successful? Or everytime? Because if its called everytime, even after login or not, you have to have some variable or something that tell that the user is logged, if so, you check this variable before calling this function.

Comment: after login. ..but if a user visits again this page the function is called again.

Comment: I see.. I believe the solution will be move the subscribe logic to the login callback. But it will work if the login is make via AJAX